# Why was ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver so slow for me?

Tags: dual-boot, intel-graphics, performance

I am not here to bitch about anything, I just want to be a member of beautiful linux community but unfortunately I had a bad experience twice.I first used Linux for a week in bachelors I had some problems which are the same ones that happened when I tried this time. Please explain if I was wrong anywhere?

I used Ubuntu, Ubuntu Mate, Ubuntu LX they all happen to have one problem in common for me.They all booted up really nice, but after 30 minutes of average use (browsing with 2-3 tabs-mostly google,netflix,wikipedia) the pc freezes and then only possible way to get out was to remove the battery or force restart

Laptop config:

- [Intel HD Graphics/6th Gen Intel Core i5 Quad core-6200U](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/88193/intel-core-i5-6200u-processor-3m-cache-up-to-2-80-ghz.html)
- 4GB DDR4

Swapping memory to ubuntu was 2.5GB..I later on set swapiness to 20 when someone said it would be faster

Alongside Windows 10 Dual Boot. Windows works good as expected.

Ubuntu works well but then that sudden freezes happen to be at anytime and unexpected. I felt bad that I had to leave Linux because I don't want to support paid software.

Things you should know- I made ubuntu install the drivers for me.Videos played well no vsync problems. I used minimum startups. and the freezes according to me tend to happen when I leave laptop for sometime alone.When i re-used it , it usually freezes at the same spot. If any other info I can provide please let me know. I would still love to re-use ubuntu if this problem is solved. I don't care if its slow I just want it working! Linux is a good thing!

Nothing worked so I came back to Windows.If Any elder takes his time ,I would really appreciate that. Thanks

Comment: You didn't say how much ram you actually have. Your video specs are fine. 8GB of DRAM is in my opinion the minimum you need to have a non-frustrating experience. KDE also has a smaller memory foot print than gnome or unity and is much faster. I'm running 18.04 and KDE on a 10 year old 6 core AMD with 16G and am pretty happy. Using about 100M of swap with 4.4GB resident with average web browsing (9 brave processes), slack, jami, konsole, etc.

Comment: I'm agree with @ppetraki. In addition I would advice you to return swapiness to its default value.

Comment: Title does not seem to match the question, which reduces the number of folks willing to read the question and help.

Comment: Whoops, my eyes are getting old. It says 4G RAM, that's not enough. I agree with @pa4080 concerning returning swappiness to it's default value. According to this, https://tinyurl.com/yxt3oz25, you should be able to address 32GB of DRAM. 16G would be ideal (~$100). If you don't already have an SSD, add one, instead of maxing out the ram.

 Let us know if you have any more questions.

Comment: @ppetraki pa4080 and user535733Thank you so much good people.I also have a friend with a laptop of slightly lesser specs.He is going through almost same trouble.SO Solution is to upgrade RAM (appx. 16 GB) and change to default swapiness..Can you also, clear this for me that Is it normal that Windows is performing *better* with same specs but not Ubuntu?   I can afford to upgrade Ram and get a SSD too I hope it brings good results to Ubuntu OS..atleast I know for sure that If I do these Windows will work flawlessly ,because its pretty good now ,just little slow after I simultaneously run 4 apps

Comment: @DeepThoughts Comparing OS's like that is comparing apples and oranges. I've seen Macs with 4GB start swapping heavily right out of the box with 1-2 tabs browser tabs. You can most certainly run *Linux* with 4GB of ram, just not with the desktop experience you've become accustomed to (window manager only, think fluxbox) and certainly not with Ubuntu out of the box. KDE is more efficient across the board. Running Win10 *without a virus scanner* with 4GB is plausible, with a virus scanner I would double the specs. Web browsing is where all the ram goes, 130+MB per sand boxed tab.

Comment: @ppetraki Hey man.I updated my RAM to 8GB it seems to be working much better. its after 4 days of use and I think I am satisfied. One thing man- I had a package installed from Software Center and it was an 'Extension' called Cpufreq. It has two settings of Performance and Power Saving mode. I want to remove it. And I am unable to do it by any way. I tried from software center it says it isn't installed. I removed it from 'Synaptic Package' but it still is there in the dock just near Wifi symbol. I want to remove it and make everything normal.Its name in 'Synaptic Packgae' is cpufrequtlis..

Comment: @DeepThoughts You should be able to just "sudo apt-get remove cpufrequtils" . It's not installed on my desktop which is fine. But on a laptop it's a good thing it's there. The CPUs will burst when they need to (you can see it on htop), it's just that they're not cooking your lap all the time for nothing. You might be over optimizing a bit IMHO. But never the less, that's how you uninstall it. You could also just set the policy to performance too. See the man pages, it's easy.

Comment: @DeepThoughts I'm glad you're happy with your computer now! :)

Comment: hey @ppetraki i tried that but it says its not installed but still i get it in the dock. there is now way to remove it and still its stuck there. apparently its just stuck there

Comment: hey man sorry to disturb again but finally i was able to remove it by installing a new frequency monitor which was diiffirent from this. it replaced the old one after the restart

Answer (score 0):

A couple of suggestions,

a) Playing around with settings without a reason will cause more problems. Reset swappiness to 60, the default for a desktop system.

b) Don't take hearsay as evidence of anything.

c) You need to gather system information to do a proper diagnosis.

I'm using https://www.monitorix.org/ because it records history of various processes and gives charts to do a visual inspection of whats going on.

On my desktops I also use https://github.com/oguzhaninan/Stacer, again for a visiual representation of whats going on.

The system activity reporting tool `sar` https://linux.die.net/man/1/sar is a more standard tool you could look into using.

It does sound like you have a hardware issue or a serious misconfiguration, these tools should help you identify the problem by gathering data you can see.

-- hope this helps